# Is there a way to increase the request size limit when inserting data into cosmosdb?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a requirement of reading multiple files (105 files) from ADLS(Azure data lake storage); parsing them and subsequently adding the parsed data directly to multiple collections in azure cosmos db for mongodb api. All this needs to be done in one request. Average file size is 120kb.
The issue is that after multiple documents are added,an error is raised "request size limit too large"
Please let me know if someone has any inputs on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear how you're performing multi-document inserts but... You can't increase maximum request size. You'll need to perform individual inserts, or insert in smaller batches.

Comment: using python;in a for loop I m reading one file at a time from adls then say I am adding that entire file to the cosmos db collection through collection.insert(file) method.That for loop runs for all the files i.e. 105 files.I am new to this,so if there's an efficient way to this,it will help a lot